# Update PHP without removing every dependency

Tags: apt, apache2, php, aptitude

I'm having an issue where I just need to do something as simple as upgrade my PHP version from 5.3 to 5.6. The only issue is that Plesk is installed and I don't know how to upgrade it without Plesk being removed along with it.

Parallels suggests that you install the versions of PHP you want before you install Plesk, but this isn't an option because my version of Plesk comes pre-installed with my vps image, which comes with php 5.3 running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

So far I have tried doing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
aptitude install php5
```

However because of dependencies it also wants to remove the following packages:

```
1)      apache2
2)      apache2-mpm-prefork
3)      apache2.2-bin
4)      apache2.2-common
5)      libapache2-mod-aclr2-psa
6)      libapache2-mod-fcgid-psa
7)      libapache2-mod-perl2
8)      libapache2-mod-php5
9)      libapache2-mod-python
10)     libapache2-mod-rpaf
11)     libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
12)     libaprutil1-ldap
13)     php5
14)     php5-cgi
15)     php5-cli
16)     php5-curl
17)     php5-fpm
18)     php5-gd
19)     php5-imap
20)     php5-mysql
21)     php5-sqlite
22)     php5-xsl
23)     plesk-core
24)     plesk-l10n
25)     pp-sitebuilder
26)     psa
27)     psa-atmail
28)     psa-backup-manager
29)     psa-horde
30)     psa-imp
31)     psa-ingo
32)     psa-kronolith
33)     psa-libxml-proxy
34)     psa-migration-agents
35)     psa-migration-manager
36)     psa-mimp
37)     psa-mnemo
38)     psa-mod-fcgid-configurator
39)     psa-passwd
40)     psa-php5-configurator
41)     psa-spamassassin
42)     psa-turba
43)     psa-updates
44)     psa-vhost
45)     sshterm
```

The 'psa' packages and 'plesk-core' etc are the packages that are associated with Plesk.

I also attempted using the following to remove the php packages but it again attempts to remove them all.

```
sudo apt-get purge php.*
```

So far I've tried multiple times and re-installed my server multiple times, each time resulting in a non-functional web environment.

So my question is, how can I remove and upgrade just php/apache but not the plesk packages?

Thanks for your help.